# AppleScript calcule time

Tags: applescript, time

I'm trying to do if statement with the current time,

e.g

> if Time is between 14h and 14:30 then ... if time is between 14:30
>   and 15h then ...

and so on.

```
time string of (current date)
set Timeleft to missing value

if time string is in "14:00:00" and "14:29:60" then

end if
```

now obviously time is not a string like i did in my script, how can I make that working?

Also here is my system time format :
current date

> ```
>   --> date "Saturday 9 December 2017 at 14:10:09"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Found a work around

```
set myTime to time string of (current date) as Unicode text
##set Timeleft to missing value

if myTime > "14:00:00" and myTime < "14:30:60" then
    display notification "!"
end if
```

Comment: How is this going to work when `myTime` is going to have `AP` or `PM` in it, e.g. `9:45:10 AM`

Comment: I don't use AM / PM in my region so I'm fine, but I suppose that wouldn't work

Comment: I guess for those that do have `AM` or `PM` in `myTime` one could use the following line of code after the `set myTime to time string of ...` line: `if (last character of myTime as text) is "M" then set myTime to characters 1 through -4 of myTime as text`